# Algebra : Prove that $P(a) = 0 \iff Q(1/a) = 0$

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebra-precalculus

$K=F_2[X]/(X^4+X+1)$ and ξ is the class of X in K

I know that the roots of P(X) = $(X^4+X+1)$ are $ξ$, $ξ^2$, $ξ^4$, $ξ^8$.

Q(X) = $X^4 + X^3 + 1$

How can I prove that Q($\alpha$) = 0 is equivalent to P($1/\alpha$) = 0 ?

Comment: Hint: what is $X^4\cdot P(\frac{1}{X})$? How about $X^4\cdot Q(\frac{1}{X})$?

Comment: Ok I see thank you ! If the first half only were right, would it work or should both work

Answer (score 2):

$\alpha^4+\alpha^3+1=0$ is equivalent to $(1/\alpha^4)(\alpha^4+\alpha^3+1)=0$ i.e $1+1/\alpha+ 1/\alpha^4=0$.

Comment: (assuming $\alpha\neq 0$ of course, but clearly the first equality can't hold if $\alpha$ were zero)

Comment: certainly $\alpha\neq 0$